# Unable to connect to 5 GHz WiFi

Tags: networking, dual-boot, network-interface, pop-os

After installing Pop!_OS in dual boot with Windows 11,
I'm only able to connect to 2.4 GHz networks. 
5 GHz networks are not even showing up in the visible networks.

WiFi Card Details.

```
description: Wireless interface
product: MT7921 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter
vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
logical name: wlp2s0
logical name: /dev/fb0
version: 00
serial: 48:e7:da:31:3b:eb
width: 64 bits
clock: 33 MHz
capabilities: pciexpress msi pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless fb
configuration: broadcast=yes depth=32 driver=mt7921e driverversion=5.19.0-76051900-generic firmware=____010000-20220209150915 ip=192.168.34.96 latency=0 link=yes mode=2560x1440 multicast=yes visual=truecolor wireless=IEEE 802.11 xres=2560 yres=1440
```

Device Details:

```
OS: Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS x86_64
Host: ROG Zephyrus G14 GA401IHR_GA401
Kernel: 5.19.0-76051900-generic
```

Comment: The card details include `logical name: /dev/fb0`, `capabilities: fb`, and `configuration: ... depth=32 ... mode=2560x1440 ... visual=truecolor ... xres=2560 yres=1440`. All of those seem like information about a **display**. Is your system currently configured to use a wireless display? If so, the 5 GHz transmitter/receiver might be busy with that and not available for generic networking.

Comment: Looks like a firmware issue or something relevant. Have you checked the official System76 [troubleshooting guide](https://support.system76.com/articles/wireless/) regarding WiFi issues?